# How to store 'event' entity type in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

What is the best way to capture events within Dynamics CRM?

E.g I know these 100 contact attended a conference / seminar on Product X, and I would like to capture that data within the system for email campaigns / reporting.

I was surprised that I wouldn't find any activity of this type.

Comment: What do you mean by 'capture key events'? Can you expand on that a little?

Comment: "capture" as in record, so that I would use that data for reporting / searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more of a business question. 
You should build a Conference (event) entity and relate the attendees (100 contacts) either manually or by some automated process. 
This will enable you to use that information in any report.

Comment: Yep. This is what I was thinking, although I would have thought that the requirement is so common, it would have been a predefined identity.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Customer Portal Accelerator.
It was initially called the Event Management Accelerator but the name has changed since and additional functionality has been added

http://dynamics-crm.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-US/applications/customer-portal-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-12884910826